# Separate main() methods to run DesktopLauncher.main() and Server using Libgdx and Kryonet

Tags: java, libgdx, kryonet

I want my GameServer to run separately from the game itself. So, players(clients) can join into one static GameServer and I can handle them together and see how many clients are connected, currently.

But the problem is, I can only run only one of these classes(GameServer.main() and DesktopLauncher.main()) at the same time. GameServer must be running always at the background if I'm not wrong, right ? Yet, I can't run the game itself without stopping the GameServer. (It stucks saying Executing task 'DesktopLauncher.main()'...) I have some pictures to realize what's going on and what project structure looks like :

[Pic 1](https://ibb.co/gWjCD7P) , [Pic 2](https://ibb.co/x5qpPQx) , [Pic 3](https://ibb.co/9qrFmqC)

Here is my project structure :

> core
> -java
> --com.mygdx.game
> ---Multiplayer
> ----Packets
> -----GameClient.java
> -----GameServer.java
> -----GameClientListener.java
> -----GameServerListener.java
> ---screens
> ---utils
> ---Application.java

**GameServer.class**

```
package com.mygdx.game.Multiplayer;


imports..

public class GameServer {

public int TCP_PORT,UDP_PORT;
public Server server;
public GameServerListener listener;

public static int totalClients = 0;

public GameServer() {

    TCP_PORT = UDP_PORT = xxxx;
    server = new Server(TCP_PORT,UDP_PORT);
    listener = new GameServerListener(this);

    startServer();
}


public void startServer() {

    server.addListener(listener);

    try {
        server.bind(TCP_PORT,UDP_PORT);
        //server.bind(TCP_PORT);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    registerPackets();
    server.start();

}

private void registerPackets() {
    server.getKryo().register(LoginRequest.class);
    server.getKryo().register(LoginResponse.class);
    server.getKryo().register(ChoiceRequest.class);
    server.getKryo().register(ChoiceRespond.class);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GameServer();
}

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please do not link to outside code. If you need to describe your class structure, please write it in text in the question.

Comment: Are you trying to use the same compiled code for your game server and the desktop client? I would always separate the two, and have the possibility of multiple types of clients (desktop, web, text...) using the exact same server.

Comment: Your game sever should include all the code to run your game over the network. It doesn't need a graphical user interface. The server admin could be special type of client, and it should not be a problem to run multiple clients with your game server.

Comment: Actually, I use the same code for both client and server, for now. I tried two scenarios. 1) If I define server,client in Screen classes of my game and run them in these classes, there is no problem, everyone can join and play. But in this case, all clients also runs a server but joins only my server. That's a mistake. 2) I thought that the idea of everybody runs a server in their device is wrong, so I decided to make a GameServer class and give a main() in it. It runs independently from clients. The GameServer class also is in my project structure but it is not called from anywhere else.

Comment: You should *never* do this. Duplicating code like this has redundant code on both the client and the server, and can be a large security hole. The client should know how to play the game, the server should know how to transfer data to and from the client.

Comment: I edited my comment because of accidentally sending while not finished.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong with the structure of the server-client interaction. Can you suggest me any document or link, example etc. ?

Comment: Try googling anything on client-server architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue. Downgrading to Android Studio 3.4 worked for me.

Check: https://www.reddit.com/r/libgdx/comments/fxrlsm/unable_to_run_two_or_more_application_in_parallel/

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I got a new approach but yours seems more legit. Btw, my new approach is to add a boolean which says the user is admin or not and runs GameServer inside the game itself if the client is marked as Admin. But yours seems definitely what I want to do.

Comment: forgot to ask, exactly, which version you recommend, 3.4 or 3.4.x ?

Comment: I haven't tried any 3.4.x version, so I don't know, sorry

Comment: Finally I tried. Android Studio 3.4 (just 3.4, not 3.4.x) worked like a charm! Now I can run my server and client (everyone of them, not just admin or outside clients) independently at the same time. Thanks! @Lordeblader